# Access many-to-one related object with async SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models:

```py
class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'a'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)


class B(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'b'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  a_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey(A.id))
  a = relationship(A)
```

Now if i fetch an object from `B` and query its `a` property with `b.a`, i get the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)
```

Putting `var = b.a` inside an `async with session.begin():` block, or calling it as `await b.a` (which is stupid in hindsight, but one must try everything) doesn’t help.

I could do

```
b_a = (await db.scalars(sa.select(A).filter(A.id == b.a_id))).one()
```

but it’s too verbose for my taste (and gets *really* messy for complex relationships).

I found a lot of solutions for the other way around (one-to-many and many-to-many), but nothing for this use case.

Update to answer questions from comments:

I create the engine and the sessionmaker like this:

```py
db_engine = create_async_engine(DB_URI, pool_recycle=3600, pool_pre_ping=True, echo_pool=True)
session_maker = sessionmaker(db_engine, AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
```

And the way i query the object of `B` is:

```py
query = sa.select(B).filter(B.id == requested_id)
result = (await db.execute(query)).one_or_none()  # type: ignore
b = result[0] if result else None
```

Comment: Did you use AsyncSession for your sessionmaker? Could you share some more code?

Answer (score 0):

modify your class B relation with this:

> a = relationship(A,lazy='selectin')

and that should work properly